# How to run multiple QTest classes?

Tags: c++, qt, unit-testing, qtestlib

I have a subproject where I put all my `QTest` unit tests and build a stand-alone test application that runs the tests (i.e. I run it from within Qt Creator). I have multiple test classes that I can execute with `qExec()`. However I don't know what is the proper way to execute multiple test classes.

Currently I do it in this way (MVCE):

### tests.pro

```
QT -= gui
QT += core \
    testlib

CONFIG += console
CONFIG -= app_bundle
TEMPLATE = app
TARGET = testrunner

HEADERS += test_foo.h
SOURCES += main.cpp
```

### main.cpp

```
#include <QtTest>
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include "test_foo.h"

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    QCoreApplication app(argc, argv);

    TestFooClass testFoo;
    TestBarClass testBar;
    // NOTE THIS LINE IN PARTICULAR.
    return QTest::qExec(&testFoo, argc, argv) || QTest::qExec(&testBar, argc, argv);
}
```

### test_foo.h

```
#include <QtTest>

class TestFooClass: public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
private slots:
    void test_func_foo() {};
};

class TestBarClass: public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
private slots:
    void test_func_bar() {};
};
```

However the [documentation for `qExec()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtest.html#qExec) says this is the wrong way:

> For stand-alone test applications, this function should not be called more than once, as command-line options for logging test output to files and executing individual test functions will not behave correctly.

The other major downside is that there is **no single summary for all the test classes**, only for individual classes. This is a problem when I have dozens of classes that each have dozens of tests. To check if all tests passed I have to scroll up to see all the "Totals" of what passed/failed of each class, e.g.:

```
********* Start testing of TestFooClass *********
PASS   : TestFooClass::initTestCase()
PASS   : TestFooClass::test_func_foo()
PASS   : TestFooClass::cleanupTestCase()
Totals: 3 passed, 0 failed, 0 skipped, 0 blacklisted
********* Finished testing of TestFooClass *********
********* Start testing of TestBarClass *********
PASS   : TestBarClass::initTestCase()
PASS   : TestBarClass::test_func_bar()
PASS   : TestBarClass::cleanupTestCase()
Totals: 3 passed, 0 failed, 0 skipped, 0 blacklisted
********* Finished testing of TestBarClass *********
```

I'm also surprised my `qExec() || qExec()` works considering that the [documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtest.html#qExec) says if a test failed `qExec()` returns a non-zero value, which should mean all the following `qExec()` calls wouldn't happen, but this seems not to be the case.

What is the proper way to run multiple test classes? And so that I can see at a glance if any of the hundreds of unit tests I have have failed.

Comment: Have you made any progress regarding this problem? The best I could find so far was the [answer to a similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10165709/1557062).

Comment: @sigy The solutions are either 1) The guys in #qt told me the proper way is to have 1 test project per test class (you can put them in a `TEMPLATE = subdirs`). Then the testrunner combines the test results. 2) Use GoogleTest, which is superior in many ways.

Comment: Hi, I have the same issue. Why should I create one project per test class. This is ridiculous. I don't want to switch to CMake :(. Is there still no solution with Qt 5 or 6? I actually prefer your solution to the one posted as answer.

Comment: The `qExec() || qExec()` works because all tests in your example **pass**, hence all `qExec()` calls return `0` (i.e. false), hence the `||` operator continues to evaluate the right-hand side. Regarding the issue with the **single summary**, see my answer below.

Answer (score 10):

I once found a nice [solution](http://qtcreator.blogspot.de/2009/10/running-multiple-unit-tests.html) using a plain Qt project (**no** `TEMPLATE = subdirs`) which uses a *macro approach* for creating the main function and automatic registering of all test classes (*macro*, too) with only a simple helper header file.

Here is a sample test class (only the relevant header file):

```
#ifndef FOOTESTS_H
#define FOOTESTS_H

#include "AutoTest.h"

class FooTests : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
    private slots:
        void initTestCase();
        void test1();
        void test2();
        void cleanupTestCase();
};

DECLARE_TEST(FooTests)

#endif // FOOTESTS_H
```

and the main, which consumes every test class created this way:

```
#include "AutoTest.h"

TEST_MAIN
```

The code of `AutoTest.h`:

```
#ifndef AUTOTEST_H
#define AUTOTEST_H

#include <QTest>
#include <QList>
#include <QString>
#include <QSharedPointer>

namespace AutoTest
{
 typedef QList<QObject*> TestList;

 inline TestList& testList()
 {
  static TestList list;
  return list;
 }

 inline bool findObject(QObject* object)
 {
  TestList& list = testList();
  if (list.contains(object))
  {
   return true;
  }
  foreach (QObject* test, list)
  {
   if (test->objectName() == object->objectName())
   {
    return true;
   }
  }
  return false;
 }

 inline void addTest(QObject* object)
 {
  TestList& list = testList();
  if (!findObject(object))
  {
   list.append(object);
  }
 }

 inline int run(int argc, char *argv[])
 {
  int ret = 0;

  foreach (QObject* test, testList())
  {
   ret += QTest::qExec(test, argc, argv);
  }

  return ret;
 }
}

template <class T>
class Test
{
public:
 QSharedPointer<T> child;

 Test(const QString& name) : child(new T)
 {
  child->setObjectName(name);
  AutoTest::addTest(child.data());
 }
};

#define DECLARE_TEST(className) static Test<className> t(#className);

#define TEST_MAIN \
 int main(int argc, char *argv[]) \
 { \
  return AutoTest::run(argc, argv); \
 }

#endif // AUTOTEST_H
```

All credits goes to [Rob Caldecott](https://www.blogger.com/profile/16139053405031925765).

Comment: I had to add `QApplication app(argc, argv);` to the `TEST_MAIN` makro (like in the original [QTEST_MAIN](https://dreamswork.github.io/qt4/qtest_8h_source.html#263) makro line 263) so the target does not show the command line help

Comment: It is better to put the macro DECLARE_TEST(FooTests) into a cpp file instead of header to prevent creation of two instances of the class although there is a protection from the double registration in AutoTest.h.  If there is a cpp implementation of FooTests the header is included into two different cpp files (there is always one auto generated moc file).

Comment: Documentation of QTest::qExec says: "this function should not be called more than once".

Answer (score 0):

To execute multiple test classes contained in a single test project, including **auto-detection** of test classes (by simply deriving from `TestClass`) and having a nice **summary** printed at the end, use the following code:

### FooTestClass.h

```
#include "TestClass.h"

class FooTestClass : public TestClass {
    Q_OBJECT
private:
    Q_SLOT void fooTest1() { }
    Q_SLOT void fooTest2() { }
};

// Note: C++17 style inline variable. In C++11, use a static variable instead.
inline FooTestClass fooTests;
```

### BarTestClass.h

```
#include "TestClass.h"

class BarTestClass : public TestClass {
    Q_OBJECT
private:
    Q_SLOT void barTest1() { }
    Q_SLOT void barTest2() { }
};

// Note: C++17 style inline variable. In C++11, use a static variable instead.
inline BarTestClass barTests;
```

### main.cpp

```
#include "TestClass.h"

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    return TestClass::runAllTests(argc, argv);
}
```

### TestClass.h

```
#include <QDebug>
#include <QObject>
#include <QString>
#include <QTest>

class TestClass : public QObject {
    Q_OBJECT

private:

    static QObjectList &testObjects() { static QObjectList testObjects; return testObjects; }

public:

    TestClass() { testObjects().append(this); }

    static int runAllTests(int argc, char **argv) {
        // Sort test objects by class name.
        std::sort(testObjects().begin(), testObjects().end(), [] (const QObject *a, const QObject *b) {
            return strcmp(a->metaObject()->className(), b->metaObject()->className()) < 0;
        });

        // Run all tests.
        QStringList results;
        int passed = 0;
        for (QObject *testObject : testObjects()) {
            bool success = false;
            try {
                success = QTest::qExec(testObject, argc, argv) == EXIT_SUCCESS;
            } catch (...) { }
            qDebug() << "";
            results << QString("%1  : %2").arg(success ? "PASS " : "FAIL!").arg(testObject->metaObject()->className());
            passed += success ? 1 : 0;
        }

        // Print summary.
        int tested = testObjects().size();
        results << QString("Totals: %1 tested, %2 passed, %3 failed").arg(tested).arg(passed).arg(tested - passed);
        results << QString("Result: %1").arg(tested == passed ? "All tests PASSED." : "Some tests FAILED!");
        qDebug() << "********* Start of summary *********";
        for (const QString &line : results) {
            qDebug() << line.toUtf8().data();
        }
        qDebug() << "********* End of summary *********";
        qDebug() << "";

        return tested == passed ? EXIT_SUCCESS : EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
};
```

### Output

```
********* Start testing of BarTestClass *********
Config: Using QtTest library 5.15.12, Qt 5.15.12 (x86_64-little_endian-llp64 shared (dynamic) release build; by GCC 13.2.0), windows 10
PASS   : BarTestClass::initTestCase()
PASS   : BarTestClass::barTest1()
PASS   : BarTestClass::barTest2()
PASS   : BarTestClass::cleanupTestCase()
Totals: 4 passed, 0 failed, 0 skipped, 0 blacklisted, 2ms
********* Finished testing of BarTestClass *********

********* Start testing of FooTestClass *********
Config: Using QtTest library 5.15.12, Qt 5.15.12 (x86_64-little_endian-llp64 shared (dynamic) release build; by GCC 13.2.0), windows 10
PASS   : FooTestClass::initTestCase()
PASS   : FooTestClass::fooTest1()
PASS   : FooTestClass::fooTest2()
PASS   : FooTestClass::cleanupTestCase()
Totals: 4 passed, 0 failed, 0 skipped, 0 blacklisted, 1ms
********* Finished testing of FooTestClass *********

********* Start of summary *********
PASS   : BarTestClass
PASS   : FooTestClass
Totals: 2 tested, 2 passed, 0 failed
Result: All tests PASSED.
********* End of summary *********
```

### Limitations of this solution

The documentation of [QTest::qExec](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtest.html#qExec) says that this function shouldn't be called more than once because "command-line options for logging test output to files and executing individual test functions will not behave correctly".

That's true, but it's only a minor issue. Just keep in mind that **some** of the [QtTest command line options](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtest-overview.html#qt-test-command-line-arguments) won't work as intended. If you don't pass any command line options at all, then you're fine in any case.