# Double validation in QTreeWidget

Tags: c++, qt, qtreewidget

I am building a program using QTreeWidget. When I double click to a child, it allows to edit this child. I write a function to validate new input value using QDoubleValidator and I want to show a error tooltip but it not work, so I have a question whether I can write a validator that check input value immediately ( like ajax in web development) and show a error tooltip ?
Can anyone have me?

Answer (score 0):

Your question is pretty inspecific because you missed the chance of providing any code.

Anyway, I think you should not need any self implemented [QValidator](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qvalidator.html), if and only if the functionality of [QDoubleValidator](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdoublevalidator.html) are sufficient.

Thing I would do is implementing a slot in the main widget/dialog whatever and connect the signal [`void QTreeWidget::itemChanged(QTreeWidgetItem *item, int column)`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtreewidget.html#itemChanged) to the created slot. Whenever any tree item changes the slot gets invoked.

Inside the slot you may do any magic for validating the change, wheter you use [QDoubleValidator](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdoublevalidator.html) or not. After any invalid check you may display an error message or pop up a [QMessageBox](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmessagebox.html).

---

If you require more information or help you have to provide more information. Feel free to generate a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). For a nice example look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37987301/how-to-run-multiple-qtest-classes).